# How can I force user to choose at least one option to go to next page Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

Im working on Quiz App using Laravel and Vue JS.

I want a user must select one option from given four options to go to next page. in other way ***NEXT*** option I want to disable until unless a user must not select at least one option.
Im using pagination i.e. one question per page.
Here are the screen shots of my program:

=> **component.vue**:

```
  <li v-for="choice in question.answers">
    <label>
      <input type="radio"
        :value="choice.is_correct==true?true:choice.answer"
        :name = "index"
        v-model = "userResponses[index]"
        @click = "choices(question.id, choice.id)"
      >
      {{choice.answer}}
    </label>
  </li>
```

=> **component.vue**: at start no option is selected

```
data() {
  return {
    questions: this.quizQuestions,
    questionIndex: 0,
    userResponses: Array(this.quizQuestions.length).fill(false),
    currentQuestion: 0,
    currentAnswer: 0,
  }
},
```

=> **component.vue**: next button

```
<div v-show="questionIndex!=questions.length">
  <!--  <button v-if="questionIndex>0" class="btn btn-success float-right"@click="prev()">Prev</button>  -->
 <button class="btn btn-success" @click="next();postuserChoices()">Next</button>
```

=> **blade.php**

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Edit your post and post the relevant code in code blocks.

Comment: Now please see!

Comment: Is `index` defined in the `li`? If you're trying to use the `index` of the current entry in the loop, make sure to define it: `<li v-for="(choice, index) in question.answers">`

Also, I suppose you can bind `disabled` in your next button to `userResponses[questionIndex]`: `<button class="btn btn-success"@click="next();postuserChoices()" :disabled="!userResponses[questionIndex]">Next</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `next()` method:

```
if (!this.userResponses[this.index]) { return }
```

Note: there are many assumptions this answer is based on. I assume that `userResponses` and `index` are defined as your component data and you have written your `next` method.

Another note: Am I seeing correctly that you are setting value of an input to true for correct answer? This is, well, a terrible idea - this basically mean I can inspect html to get 100% from your quiz.